# A 1-form on a smooth manifold is exact if and only if it integrates to zero on every closed curve

Tags: integration, manifolds, differential-forms

I am stuck on the following problem, which comes from a old qualifying exam.

Prove that a 1-form $\phi$ on $M$ is exact if and only if for every closed curve
c, $\int_{c} \phi =0$.

One way is an application of Stokes' theorem,
if $\phi = df$ then $\int_{c}\phi = \int_{\partial C}df = 0$ since $\partial B=\emptyset$.

I don't know how to do the other direction. I made an attempt as follows:

Choose any $x_0 \in M$ define a function, $f(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x}\phi$. This makes sense since the integral is path independent. Now I want to prove that $f$ is smooth and $df=\phi$. I can't do either.

Thanks

Comment: You may not be able to prove $f$ is smooth -- in general, it's not -- but it's once-differentiable. The proof looks a lot like the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus (of which this is just a generalization). Same goes for $df = \phi$.

Comment: Is the theorem true? Do I need extra requirements?

Comment: I think I can do it, if I assume that $H^1 =0$.

Comment: You don't need to assume $H^1=0$. But to prove $f$ is smooth, you have to assume that $\phi$ is smooth.  To prove that $df=\phi$ at a point $p$, you can work in coordinates centered at $p$, in which case what you need to show is that $\partial f/\partial x^i(p) = \phi_i(p)$ for each $i$, where the coordinate representation of $\phi$ is $\sum_i \phi_i dx^i$.  You can do this by carefully choosing a path whose last part travels along the $x^i$-axis in these coordinates. The proof is carried out in detail in my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ (2nd ed.), Theorem 11.42.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are discussing the problem in the context of differential geometry, so $M$ is a smooth manifold, $\phi$ is a smooth 1-form. The smoothness of $f(x)=\int_{x_0}^x \phi$ is a local property so we should be able to prove that by applying fundamental theorem of calculus in $\mathbf R ^n$.